# Html to pdf conversion free open source component in .net

Tags: .net, pdf

i need a HTML to pdf component,which can convert the html to pdf with all the styles and designs...i have used itextsharp but the styles cannot be produced after conversion to pdf...

i need some free open source component to make the pdf conversion please help with valuable suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this task I've used [xhtmlrenderer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) together with [ikvmc](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html) (to compile to a .NET assembly). I've used the following commands to compile the JAR file:

```
ikvmc -target:library itext.jar
ikvmc -target:library -reference:itext.dll core-renderer.jar
```

You will also need to put all the IKVM assemblies that the resulting file will have dependency on into your project.

As an alternative you could take a look at [Aspose.Pdf](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) which is a good commercial component.

Answer (score 0):

Try:   https://www.articlage.com/adrianillo/article/htmltopdf

It´s MIT License.

Transform basic html and css, but  html5 and css3  remains to be completed.

You can add code for completing librery, the code is: https://github.com/adrianillo/HtmlToPdf